# Get mean of cells with different dimensions

Tags: matlab, mean

I have 24 cells, some have the dimensions of 16x1, some 15x1, and some 14x1. I'd like to create one 16x1 cell with each row being the the mean of the same rows from those 24 cells. Any 'missing' values would be ignored (i.e., not included in the average). To make my question clearer, here is an example of what I have:

A1 is a 14x1 cell, A2: 16x1, A3: 16x1, A4: 15x1, A5: 14x1, A6: 16x1 etc.

If I do:

M=cell(16,1)

for n=1:16

M(n)=mean([A1(n,1) A2(n,1) A3(n,1) ... A24(n,1)]

end

This, of course, would give me a 16x1 M but the last two rows (i.e. M(15,1) and M(16,1) would be empty.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: This can be probably done with `arrayfun` or `cellfun`. Please add a small example cell array and the expected answer.

Comment: An example would be A1=[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]' and A2=[4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]'. So A1 is 16x1 and A2 is 14x1. M would be expected to be M=[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2]'. Note the last two values of M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
Acell = {A1,A2,A3,A4,....};
maxL = max(cellfun(@length, Acell))
M = zeros(maxL,1);
for n=1:maxL
    M(n) = mean(cellfun(@(V) V(n), Acell((cellfun(@length, Acell))>=n)))
end
```

`cellfun` applies some function (first argument) to each element in cell array.

---

**Explanation:**

First create a cell array `Acell` from your vectors

```
Acell = {A1,A2,A3,A4,....};
```

Get the maximum length of the vectors in `Acell`

```
maxL = max(cellfun(@length, Acell))
```

This returns the n-th element of each vector in `Acell` (A1(n), A2(n), A3(n), ...). However, if n is larger than any of the length of the vectors, this fails.

```
cellfun(@(V) V(n), Acell)
```

This creates a temporary cell array of the vectors whose lengths are equal to or larger than n.

```
Acell((cellfun(@length, Acell))>=n)
```

Combining above, this returns the n-th element of each vector in `Acell` whose lengths are equal to or larger than n. Then, you can just take the mean of the values returned from this function.

```
cellfun(@(V) V(n), Acell((cellfun(@length, Acell))>=n))
```